# Unity: flash at frequency with variable on/off ratio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flashing

I want to be able to flash stuff at a certain frequency. For an example, let's say 2Hz. I also want to be able to specify a ratio, where I can have the thing displayed for let's say 2/3 of the cycle and have it hidden for 1/3, so the ratio would be 2:1. It's a wild bunch of flashing, so I Need to stay flexible in the way I do it. There might be some flashing with a ratio of 3:5 and a frequency of 2Hz, and some other flashing at 4Hz with ratio 1:1, and so on.

Also, I need to be able to flash in sync. So if one object is flashing already and I start flashing another one, they need to be in sync (or rather their cycles need to be in sync, the flashing may vary as the ratio may be different). But if at the same frequency, they need to "turn on" at the same time, even if their ratios are different. Also, they all need to turn on at the same time the slowest turns on.

My current approach: I have a GameObject FlashCycle, that essentially in it's update method calculates a progress for the 3 frequency's I have (2Hz, 4Hz and 8Hz).

```
 float time = Time.time;
 twoHerzProgress = (time % twoHerzInSeconds) / twoHerzInSeconds;
 fourHerzProgress = (time % fourHerzInSeconds) / fourHerzInSeconds;
 eightHerzProgress = (time % eightHerzInSeconds) / eightHerzInSeconds;
```

I have tried different `time`s, but that didn't really matter so let's just stick to that one if you don't think it's a bad idea!

Now, whenever I want to flash an object, in it's own `Update()` I do this:

```
switch (flashRate.herz)
    {
        case FlashRateInterval.twoHerz:
            show = flashCycle.oneHerzProgress <= onTimePercentage;
        case FlashRateInterval.fourHerz:
            show =flashCycle.twoHerzProgress <= onTimePercentage;
        case FlashRateInterval.eightHerz:
            show =flashCycle.fourHerzProgress <= onTimePercentage;
        default:
            show =true;
    }
```

and then just continue and have the object displayed if `show == true`.

Unfortunately this doesn't flash the objects at a nice smooth and regular interval. I measured the 2Hz interval and got differences in the ratio of up to 48ms, and though it seems like not much it really makes a difference on the screen.

So the question boils down to: How can I get quick, reqular flashes while maintaining the flexibility (ratio and frequency wise) and have a syncronized flash?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds-ctor.html) to achieve that

```
// onRatio and offRatio are "optional" parameters
// If not provided, they will simply have their default value 1
IEnumerator Flash(float frequency ,float onRatio = 1, float offRatio = 1)
{

    float cycleDuration = 1.0f / frequency;
    float onDuration = (onRatio/ (onRatio + offRatio)) * cycleDuration;
    float offDuration = (offRatio/ (onRatio + offRatio)) * cycleDuration; 

    while(true)
    {
        show = true;

        yield return new WatForSeconds(onDuration);        

        show = false;

        yield return new WatForSeconds(offDuration);
    }
}
```

so you can call it either with a frequency e.g. 8Hz

```
StartCoroutine(Flash(8.0f));
```

this is actually equal to any call where you set `onRatio = offRatio` e.g.

```
StartCoroutine(Flash(8.0f, onRatio = 1, offRatio = 1));

StartCoroutine(Flash(8.0f, onRatio = 2, offRatio = 2));

....
```

or with a frequency and ratios e.g. 1(on):2(off) with 8Hz

```
StartCoroutine(Flash(8.0f, onRatio = 1, offRatio = 2));
```

---

With this setup the Coroutine runs "forever" in the `while(true)`-loop. So, don't forget before you start a new Coroutine with different parameters to first stop all routines with

```
 StopAllCoroutines();
```

---

Now if you want to change that dynamically in an Update method, you would have to add some controll flags and additional variables in roder to make sure a new Coroutine is only called when something changed:

```
FlashRateInterval currentInterval;
float currentOnRatio = -1;
float currentOffRatio = -1;

void Update()
{
    // if nothing changed do nothing
    if(flashRate.herz == currentInterval
       //todo && Mathf.Approximately(<yourOnRatio>, currentOnRatio)
       //todo && Mathf.Approximately(<yourOffRatio>, currentOffRatio)
    ) return;

    StopAllCoroutines();

    currentInterval = flashRate.herz;
    //todo currentOnRatio = <yourOnRatio>;
    //todo currentOffRatio = <yourOffRatio>;

    switch (flashRate.herz)
    {
        case FlashRateInterval.twoHerz:
            StartCoroutine(2.0f);
            //todo StartCoroutine(2.0f, onRatio = <yournRatio>, offRatio = <yourOffRatio>);
        case FlashRateInterval.fourHerz:
            StartCoroutine(4.0f);
            //todo StartCoroutine(4.0f, onRatio = <yournRatio>, offRatio = <yourOffRatio>);
        case FlashRateInterval.eightHerz:
            StartCoroutine(8.0f);
            //todo StartCoroutine(8.0f, onRatio = <yournRatio>, offRatio = <yourOffRatio>);
        default:
            show =true;
    }
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. I dont know your `FlashRateInterval` but if you need to use it for some reason you could make it like

   ```
   public enum FlashRateInterval
   {
       AllwaysOn,

       twoHerz = 2,
       fourHerz = 4,
       eightHerz = 8
   }
   ```

   in order to directly use the correct values.
2. I would call a frequency variable `flashRate.herz`. You also wouldn't call a size value `cube.meters`. I'ld recommend to rename it to `flashRate.frequency`.

---

To archieve that syncing you would somehow need access to all Behaviours and compare their values (so I'ld say some `static List<YourBehavior>`) and than e.g. in the Coroutine wait until all bools are e.g. set to true before continuing with your own one. For that you would need an additional bool since it is possible that `show` is true permanently on one component.

```
public bool isBlinking;

IEnumerator Flash(float frequency ,float onRatio = 1, float offRatio = 1)
{
    //todo: You'll have to set this false when not blinking -> in Update
    isBlinking = true;

    float cycleDuration = 1.0f / frequency;
    float onDuration = (onRatio/ (onRatio + offRatio)) * cycleDuration;
    float offDuration = (offRatio/ (onRatio + offRatio)) * cycleDuration; 

    // SYNC AT START
    show = false;

    // wait until all show get false
    foreach(var component in FindObjectsOfType<YOUR_COMPONENT>())
    {
        // skip checking this component
        if(component == this) continue;

        // if the component is not running a coroutine skip
        if(!component.isBlinking) continue;

        // Now wait until show gets false
        while(component.show)
        {
            // WaitUntilEndOfFrame makes it possible
            // for us to check the value again already before
            // the next frame
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame;
        }
    }

    // => this line is reached when all show are false

    // Now lets just do the same but this time wating for true
    // wait until all show get false
    foreach(var component in FindObjectsOfType<YOUR_COMPONENT>())
    {
        // skip checking this component
        if(component == this) continue;

        // if the component is not running a coroutine skip
        if(!component.isBlinking) continue;

        // Now wait until show gets false
        while(!component.show)
        {
            // WaitUntilEndOfFrame makes it possible
            // for us to check the value again already before
            // the next frame
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame;
        }
    }

    // this line is reached when all show are getting true again => begin of loop

    while(true)
    {

    .........
```

Instead of using `FindObjectsOfType<YOUR_COMPONENT>()` which is kind of slow you could also do something like

```
public static List<YOUR_COMPONENT> Components = new List<YOUR_COMPONENT>();

private void Awake()
{
    if(!Components.Contains(this)){
        Components.Add(this);
    }
}
```

so you also get currently disabled components and objects

Comment: What I'm trying to explain with `sync` is that when I make another object flash, it shall not start on its own but flash in sync with others. And that across frequencies, so that when the slowest flashing turns off everyone else needs turn off as well (with the fastes flashing turning on first afterwards). I'm kinda thinking in a sin wave, where frequencies multiply it, yet when the "longest" wave is at "0°" again, all others are too eventhough they have passed "0°" before. I don't know if that made it easier to understand but I appreciate your long answer already!

Comment: Maybe this will do it: They all need to turn on at the same time even if they have different ratios. If they have different frequencies, they all need to turn on at the same moment the slowest does (and then more often then the slowest) Thats why the frequecies are all 2^x.

Comment: well if you make the `show` public so you can access them all you can do how I said in my last section and right before starting a new coroutine check if `show` is true on all components. Before you could add another check if they are off -> They all start the same time. since you have 2^x they should be off again all the same time at the end (offcourse this will not work anymore with flexible float requencies)

Comment: I tried to scatch this out a bit see my updated bottom section

Answer (score 0):

You got some diferences because you are doing everything in an Update() cycle with <= condition. On slower/faster machines you will have more/less differences because the frame's duration will never be equal to your frequency.

Try doing everything in a Corotine: [unity coroutine docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
//bad code below but i think its more understandable like this
IEnumerator Flash() 
{
   while(true)
   {
     BlinkOn();
     Sync();//sync here another cicle if you want to sync when on starts
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(yourDuration);// yourDuration*multiplier/something+0.5f....ecc

     BlinkOff()
     Sync();//sync here another cicle if you want to sync when of starts
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(yourDuration);
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `yield return` otherwise your Coroutine ends after the first frame.

Comment: Would it be smart / would it work if I used a coroutine that "fires" at the fastes rate (8Hz in my case) and skip every other for the 4Hz and three out of four for the 2Hz? I kinda like the thinking of a centralized place where the flashing is done, and think of having that piece of code (even if rewritten to all possible beauty!) running in every GameObject as bad?

Comment: Ahh okay, so the problem with your suggestion is that I will have a hard time having multiple objects flash in sync while having different flash ratios unless I have one coroutine running for each of them (and even then they'll probably be off at some Point). Even if they have a different ratio I Need them to "turn on" all at the same time (aka have the same beginning of their cycle).